# apk file under bin/classes directory instead of bin folder

Tags: android

It's odd. When i compile my code, so far i have seen the apk file under the bin folder of the main project tree. But recently, on this new project, it's getting placed under the bin/classes subdirectory. The apk file works as expected. But i was wondering why it got moved to bin/classes instead of bin folder.

There has been no change in my development environment in between.

The only thing that i can think of is : Under src folder, i now have an "org" subdir in addition to the customary "com" folder. I have some library code in the "org" folder and most of my app related code is in the "com" folder. Can this be the reason?

Any thoughts highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Ignore my question please.
I found the reason why.

In Eclipse, under Project Props, Build Path option, we can manually set the output folder. For  some reason it was automatically set as "..../bin/classes" instead of ".../bin/" where i was used to seeing the apk file.

Thanks and sorry for the distraction.